# Appropriateness of using assertion

Tags: assertions

Hello I found a question related to assertion. It asks that what lines have appropriately used the assertion statements.

```
        23. int =5;
        24.
        25. public void stuff1(int x){
        26. assert(x>0);
        27. switch(x){
        28.     case 2:x=3;
        29.     default:assert false;
            }
            }
        30.
        31. private void stuff2(int y){
                assert(y<0);
            }
        32.
        33. private void stuff3(){
                assert(stuff4());
            }
        34.
        35. private boolean stuff4(){
                z=6; 
                return false;
            }
```

The correct answer is "The assert statements on line 29 and 31 are used appropriately".

But I feel the use of assert in line 29 is not useful as it always gives an assertion error. If x is 2 still the default will be run and will give an assertion error. Why have the answer says that it has used the assertion in line 29 appropriately. Please someone explains me.

And also I feel like assertion in line 33 will not be appropriated as again stuff4() method call will always return false and assertion will be false always. Is it correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are only 22 lines in your code listing, so I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: As we don't have the original line numbers from the original code, can you please refer to the statements by citing it?

Comment: Im sorry corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assert(false) is fine. It is a machine readable version of the comment

```
// should never be reached
```

I always think of asserts as machine readable (and enforceable) comments

assert(stuff4()) is different. It looks like it is testing the return value of stuff4. This is bad since in non debug builds stuff4 wont be called (for most assert implementations); typically the assert macro compiles to nothing in non debug builds

Comment: But may I know that why an assertion would be useful there?

Comment: you are saying that x can only have a value of 2.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion on line 29 asserts that any other value than 2 for x is not valid, in general on the switch case block it ensures, that only defined cases are valid and the default case is not.

The assertion on line 33 is not appropriate, because it depends on an outcome of a method which is not used for checking, so yes you're right.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. But in the switch block since break statements are not included always the default assertion would run. So how can we sort defined case and default case, as it always returns the default assertion error. I'm sorry if I'am asking the same question. I'm totally new to java..

Comment: In this special case only a x value of 2 is valid. In any other case the assertion is raised. But you're right there should be a break, but this is another failure.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per the assertion rules you can not use assertion to validate public method arguments, so here assert at line 26 is not appropriate.
2. We can also use assertion at place where the flow must not go or lets say for cases never supposed to happen. So, here flow should not go to default case. (but as again break statement is not there, AssertionError will be there ). That is the reason assert at line 29 is appropriate.
3. Assert at line 31 is used correctly to validate private method argument.
4. Assert at line 33 is not appropriate as it does not leave the program in the same state as it was before the assertion. If assertion is disabled it will not run the code.